# Basic Neural Net Predictions?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I'm looking at this very basic neural net from https://machinelearningmastery.com/tutorial-first-neural-network-python-keras/. I replaced the data used with just a random array of numbers and random labels.

I'm assuming since the input is random, the predictions should be around 0.50, plus or minus a bit. However, when I do this, I get

```
[0.49525392, 0.49652839, 0.49729034, 0.49670222, 0.49342978, 0.49490061, 0.49570397, 0.4962129, 0.49774086, 0.49475089, 0.4958384, 0.49506786, 0.49696651, 0.49869373, 0.49537542, 0.49613148, 0.49636957, 0.49723724]
```

which is around 0.50, but never goes over. It does it for whatever random seed I use, so it isn't just coincidental, either. Any explanations for this behavior?

```
# Create first network with Keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(90)

X_train = np.random.rand(18,61250)
X_test = np.random.rand(18,61250)
Y_train = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,])
Y_test = np.array([1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,])

_, input_size = X_train.shape

# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=input_size, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))

# Compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# calculate predictions
predictions = model.predict(X_test)
preds = [x[0] for x in predictions]
print(preds)

# Fit the model
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=10,  verbose=2, validation_data=(X_test,Y_test))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this accurately answers your question, but I was playing around
with your code and decided to try something. Your X data is generated between 0
and 1, so I tried generating it between 0 and 10. This is a sample of the
resulting prediction:

```
[0.53419214, 0.55088341, 0.53190422, 0.52382213, 0.53469753, 0.53098464,
0.51968938, 0.53249627, 0.52852863, 0.52497149, 0.52816379, 0.5457474,
0.52565753, 0.5276686, 0.52042121, 0.52128422, 0.52535951, 0.52730507]
```

As you can see, it now produces results over 0.5. Because you predict the
    output before any training has taken place, the prediction will be done with
    random weights. Could it be that the network hasn't adjusted yet to the
    distribution of the input vector?

These are the predictions after training:

```
[0.43440229, 0.48104468, 0.49194154, 0.4766106, 0.50065982, 0.47388917,
0.51052755, 0.50618082, 0.48478326, 0.4846094, 0.50018799, 0.4800632,
0.4181695, 0.48307362, 0.5063237, 0.50420266, 0.47321039, 0.44235682]
```

The predictions are now more or less balanced. I get this kind of
    output with both input distributions. I think it is a matter of the
    randomly initialized network being very dependent on the distribution of
    your input data. After training it normalizes.

Comment: Thanks!! I noticed that the net was sometimes greater than 50%, but I figured I was doing something to make it favor one side. Doing predictions after training makes more sense.